# Assignment operator copying everything except for the free space in the array

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, queue, operator-overloading

I've been playing around with dynamic allocation and queue recently. Keep in mind that I am fairly new to data structures and I’ve been teaching myself by watching YouTube tutorials and reading some tutorials from websites so forgive my ignorance if I don’t know every single thing there is to know about this subject. However, while playing around with the implementation of an assignment operator for my queue, I seem to have made a mistake somewhere in its code. You see whenever I try and use the assignment operator

i.e.

```
Queue names2;
names2 = names;
```

the assignment operator copies everything already in the queue except the empty elements of the array. Am I implementing my copy constructor or my assignment operator wrong that is causing it to not add the empty unused capacity to the newly created queue?

**main.cpp**

```
  #include "Queue.h";

int main()
{
    Queue names;
    names.enqueue("A");
    names.enqueue("B");
    names.enqueue("C");
    names.dequeue();
    names.enqueue("D");
    names.showFullQueue();
    Queue names2;
    names2 = names;
    names2.showFullQueue();
    names2.enqueue("Tom");
    names2.enqueue("Alice");
    names2.showFullQueue();

    return 0;
}
```

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef Queue_H
#define Queue_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Queue {
public:
    Queue(); //Defualt costructor
    Queue(const Queue& source); //Copy constructor
    ~Queue(); //Destructor

    Queue& operator=(const Queue& source); //Assignament Operator //NOT WORKING

    void enqueue(string value); // add item to queue
    string dequeue(); // remove item from queue

    void showFullQueue() const;

    //memory allocation
    void memory(int currentCapacity);
private:
    void shift();
    string * arr;
    const static int front = 0;
    int back;
    int capacity;
    int usedCapacity;
};


#endif // !Queue_H
```

**Queue.cpp**

```
#include "Queue.h"

Queue::Queue()
{
    back = -1;
    capacity = 1;
    usedCapacity = 0;
    arr = new string[capacity];
}

Queue::Queue(const Queue & source)
{
    cout << "Invoking copy constructor" << endl;
    this->back = source.back;
    this->capacity = source.capacity;
    this->usedCapacity = source.usedCapacity;
    arr = new string[source.capacity];
    copy(source.arr, source.arr + usedCapacity, this->arr);
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
    delete[] arr;
}

Queue & Queue::operator=(const Queue & source)
{
    if (this == &source)
        return *this;
    cout << "Invoking Assignament operator" << endl;
    Queue temp(source);
    swap(temp.back, back);
    swap(temp.capacity, capacity);
    swap(temp.usedCapacity, capacity);
    swap(temp.arr, arr);

    return *this;
}

void Queue::enqueue(string value)
{
    ++back;
    arr[back] = value;
    usedCapacity++;
    memory(usedCapacity);
}

string Queue::dequeue()
{
    string returnValue = arr[front];
    shift();
    usedCapacity--;
    memory(usedCapacity);
    return returnValue;
}

void Queue::showFullQueue() const
{
    cout << "Front: " << front << endl;
    cout << "Back: " << back << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Queue::memory(int currentCapacity)
{
    if (currentCapacity >= capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity = (currentCapacity * 3) / 2 + 1;
        string * arr2 = new string[newCapacity];
        copy(arr, arr + usedCapacity, arr2);
        delete[] arr;
        arr = arr2;
        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
    else
        cout << "allocation error";
}

void Queue::shift()
{
    for (int i = front; i <= back; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    --back;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please remove all and put only the [MCVE]

Comment: You would have saved yourself a whole lot of stress if you used `std::vector<std::string>` rather than `std::string*`

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to play around with dynamic string arrays. I'll will use vectors next time, but for now, I just wanted to know how to implement a queue without using vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a couple of bugs here to fix..

- Your use of the data member `back` and the static member `front` seem redundant to me.
- I don't see any beneficial use of `shift` function.

Also, In your copy assignment operator...

```
Queue & Queue::operator=(const Queue & source)
{
    if (this == &source)
        return *this;
    cout << "Invoking Assignament operator" << endl;
    Queue temp(source);
    swap(temp.back, back);
    swap(temp.capacity, capacity);
    swap(temp.usedCapacity, capacity);    //Notice the Bug here...?
    swap(temp.arr, arr);

    return *this;
}
```

---

Well, here is a cleaned up version... (notice a few changes like **not `using namespace std;`** in global scope of a header file; and moving unnecessary `#includes` to the implementation file...

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef Queue_H
#define Queue_H

#include <string>

//using namespace std; ...typically a bad idea in header files

class Queue {
public:
    Queue(); //Defualt costructor
    Queue(const Queue& source); //Copy constructor
    ~Queue(); //Destructor

    Queue& operator=(const Queue& source); //Assignment Operator // WORKING :-)

    void enqueue(std::string value); // add item to queue
    string dequeue(); // remove item from queue

    void showFullQueue() const;

private:
    std::string* arr;
    int capacity;
    int usedCapacity;

    //memory allocation
    void memory(int currentCapacity);    
};


#endif // !Queue_H
```

**Queue.cpp**

```
#include "Queue.h"
//You can put the remaining includes here
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; // You can us it in your cpp file... Not a bad idea.. :-)

Queue::Queue()
{
    capacity = 3;
    usedCapacity = 0;
    arr = new string[capacity]();
}

Queue::Queue(const Queue & source)
{
    cout << "Invoking copy constructor" << endl;
    capacity = source.capacity;
    usedCapacity = source.usedCapacity;
    arr = new string[source.capacity]();
    copy(source.arr, source.arr + source.capacity, arr);
}

Queue::~Queue()
{
    delete[] arr;
}

Queue & Queue::operator=(const Queue & source)
{
    if (this == &source)
        return *this;
    cout << "Invoking Assignament operator" << endl;

    using std::swap; //For ADL: ...redundant here... since you already have using namespace std;
    Queue temp(source);
    swap(temp.capacity, capacity);
    swap(temp.usedCapacity, usedCapacity);
    swap(temp.arr, arr);

    return *this;
}

void Queue::enqueue(string value)
{
    memory(usedCapacity);
    arr[usedCapacity] = value;
    ++usedCapacity;
}

string Queue::dequeue()
{
    string returnValue = arr[--usedCapacity];
    //memory(usedCapacity); //needless
    return returnValue;
}

void Queue::showFullQueue() const
{

    //This styple prevents printing the last comma on the last item
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < usedCapacity-1; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

void Queue::memory(int currentCapacity)
{
    if (currentCapacity >= capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity = (currentCapacity * 3) / 2 + 1;
        string* arr2 = new string[newCapacity]();
        copy(arr, arr + capacity, arr2);
        delete[] arr;
        arr = arr2;
        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

And there were no changes to your **main.cpp** ...:-)
See it Working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72d7c3792e09dcf8)

Of cause, there are a few more improvements we can make like

- Thinking about [Exception Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853243/c-do-you-really-write-exception-safe-code)
- Using [Member Initialization List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)
- [Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understand what I did wrong. I will certainly try to improve my skills in the areas you pointed. Again, thank you for your tremendous help.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, you are welcome... Its a tough job, but we are all learning it... So, more grease to your elbow!

Answer (score 0):

In  `Queue & Queue::operator=(const Queue & source)` , I think you are making a wrong assignment.

```
swap(temp.capacity, capacity);
swap(temp.usedCapacity, capacity);
```

I assume it should be:

```
swap(temp.capacity, capacity);
swap(temp.usedCapacity, usedCapacity);
```