# How to read UTF 8 encoded file in java with turkish characters

Tags: java, utf-8

I am trying to read a UTF-8 encoded txt file, which has some turkish characters. Basically I am have written an axis based web service, which reads this file and send the output back as a string. Somehow I am not able to read the characters properly. The code is very simple as mentioned here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;

public class TurkishWebService {

    public String generateTurkishString() throws IOException {
        InputStream isr = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/" + "turkish.txt");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,
                "UTF8"));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        in.close();
        return str;
    }

    public String normalString() {
        System.out.println("webService normal text");
        return "webService normal text";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        new TurkishWebService().generateTurkishString();
    }
}
```

Here are the contents of turkish.txt, just one line

```
Assalğçğıİİööşş
```

I am getting the stdout as

```
Assal?τ????÷÷??
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Make sure the console you use to display the output is also encoded in UTF-8. In Eclipse, you need to go to Run Configuration to do this.

Comment: @Thihara Post an answer?

Comment: It seemed too small for an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be correctly decoding the file data from UTF-8 to UTF-16 strings.

`System.out` performs transcoding operations from UTF-16 strings to the [default JRE character encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29). If this does not match the encoding used by the device receiving the character data is corrupted. So, the console should be set to the default character encoding or data corruption occurs. How this is done is device-dependent.

If you are using a terminal, [the Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) does a better job of determining the device encoding.

*Note: it is better to use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) or at least [try-finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194261/raii-in-java-is-resource-disposal-always-so-ugly) to close streams; use [the standard encoding constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) if available.*

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the console you use to display the output is also encoded in UTF-8. In Eclipse for example, you need to go to `Run Configuration` > `Common` to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good. The problem should be in console output that cannot print Turkish. To be sure make a temp test in your program: take the string with Assal?τ????÷÷?? that you read from file and do this

```
 System.out.println(str.charAt(6) == 'ğ');
```