# Inserting values with special characters into SQLite with Java

Tags: java, sqlite, character-encoding

- I have a line with the word "Tác" in a UTF8 saved file. (Special Character á)
- I read the file in Java as follow :

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
- In Eclipse Debugmode my Value of the word I fetch from the File is T�c !
- When inserting into my SQlite DB the same -> T�c
- In my existing SQLite-DB already exists entries with special characters like "Concepción"

Additional Info : Writing System.out like follow :

```
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
                out.println(sSitename);
```

results in:
Tï¿½c

Anyone do have a hint how I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like its not really reading out in UTF8, have you tried "UTF-8"?

Check out the [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) documentation.

Comment: Yes it looks like its not reading UTF8. The Question is howto read a saved UTF8 File ? Or What am I doing wrong ? See I use the "UTF8" Parameter in InputStreamReader.

Comment: I mean, try this: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Thanks for helping, but its the same result. I see your point with '-' I missed perhabs, but the same result.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435525/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-file-in-java-with-turkish-characters

Comment: Sorry my fault ! The File was in ansi after copying the file into my vmware instance. I do not understand why, but on my local instance it is UTF8 , after dragging the file into the vmware instance the file is ansi, but I see the special characters correct. After saving as UTF-8 it works perfect. Thanks aniway.