# Java InputStreamReader Can not read Special(Turkish) Characters

Tags: java, file, character-encoding

Below you can see my code;

```
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"UTF-8"));// tried also "iso-8859-9"
String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    total += "\n" + strLine;
}
br.close();
```

Here below is the output.. what should i do?

**`insan�n sec�ld�g� combobox`**

Comment: Side note: don't use `+=` for `String` objects. Strings are immutable and you are creating many and many new String objects. Use `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings in loops.

Comment: is that possible that console you are using does not support unicode characters ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435525/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-file-in-java-with-turkish-characters

Answer (score 1):

The � or U+FFFD character is a special character defined by Unicode as a "replacement character", a character to display when you encounter a character you don't recognize, or the byte data is malformed and a character cannot be read.

The `InputStreamReader` constructor you are using does not allow you to specify the behavior when there is malformed data or when a character is not recognized.  It assumes you want the default behavior of using the "replacement character" when there is an unrecognized character or when the byte data is malformed, so that may be what your seeing.

If you examine your output and find that your Turkish characters are not there but have been replaced by the "replacement character" U+FFFD, you can change the behavior to throw an exception instead of using the replacement character -- an actual exception will make it easier to detect when data is in the wrong character set.

To specify this different behavior, use this version of `InputStreamReader`

```
public InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)
```

For the `CharsetDecoder`, pass in

```
charset.newDecoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
        .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
```

where `charset` is your character set of choice, e.g. `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

That will cause an exception to be thrown rather than the replacement character inserted.

If you still see the replacement character and no exception is thrown, it's fairly clear that the problem is in how you are viewing the output.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the actual file encoding? Open up a hex editor and look at the byte values for `insan�n` (especially the broken character). Then when you have the byte value, you can find the actual encoding. Now you've just tried two wrong encodings at random.

Answer (score 0):

[Cp1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) encoding is what your are looking for to encode special Turkish characters.

```
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"Cp1254"));
```